# Parse string using regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I had like to pass the following string via Regex to extract the domain name and the numeric value next to ms.

```
stackoverflow.com : [0], 96 bytes, 223 ms (223 avg, 0% loss)
```

I need:

```
stackoverflow.com , 223
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? Please share. Then, we'll know better what you actually need: an array, or just separate values, 1 regex or 2...

Comment: Did you try anything before posting?

Answer (score 2):

Use following `regex`:

```
(\w+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}).+?(\d+)\s+ms
```

**Explanation**

1. `()`: Capturing group
2. `\w+`: Match any alphanumeric characters any number of times
3. `\.`: Match `.` literal
4. `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`: Match the two or three alphabets
5. `.+?`: Matches any characters except linebreak
6. `\d+`: Matches any number of digits

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nY7tQ4/1)

Answer (score 1):

the following seems to work

```
(\w+\.\w+) : .*, ([0-9]+) ms
```

Tested [here](http://fiddle.re/g1u6h6)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(\w+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}).+?(\d+)\s+ms
```

Should work.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qI0xN6/1